# get xml as string instead of class with xstream

Tags: java, xml-parsing, xml-serialization, xstream

I have xml something like

```
<parent>
  <message>
   <type>15</type>
  </message>
</parent>
```

Instead of creating a message object inside parent object, I need to represent message just as a String . So , when I do parent.message , the output is `<type> 15 </type>` instead of a message object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idia is to build up the xml of message by processing the `HierarchicalStreamReader`. If you go down into `<messsage>` by calling `reader.goDown()` unfortunately `reader.getValue()` does not return the whole content of this element.

Model

```
    @XStreamAlias("parent")
    @XStreamConverter(value = ParentConverter.class)
    public class Parent {
        private final String message;

        public Parent(final String message) { this.message = message; }
        public String getMessage() { return message; }
    }
```

Converter

```
    public class ParentConverter implements Converter {
        @Override
        public boolean canConvert(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") final Class type) {
            return Parent.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
        }

        @Override
        public void marshal(Object source, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer,
                MarshallingContext context) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("unmarshaling only");
        }

        @Override
        public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader,
                UnmarshallingContext context) {

            reader.moveDown();
            if (!"message".equals(reader.getNodeName())) {
                throw new ConversionException("Expected message, but was "
                        + reader.getNodeName());
            }
            final StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
            while (reader.hasMoreChildren()) {
                reader.moveDown();
                buildRecursiveMessage(reader, message);
                reader.moveUp();
            }
            reader.moveUp();

            final Parent parent = new Parent(message.toString());
            return parent;
        }

        private void buildRecursiveMessage(final HierarchicalStreamReader reader,
                final StringBuilder sb) {
            // Build start-tag
            final String nodeName = reader.getNodeName();
            sb.append("<" + nodeName);

            // Build attributes
            final int numAttributes = reader.getAttributeCount();
            if (numAttributes > 0) {
                sb.append(" ");
                for (int i = 0; i < numAttributes; i++) {
                    final String attributeName = reader.getAttributeName(i);
                    final String attributeValue = reader.getAttribute(i);
                    sb.append(attributeName + "=\"" + attributeValue + "\"");

                    final boolean lastAttribute = (i == numAttributes - 1);
                    if (!lastAttribute) {
                        sb.append(", ");
                    }
                }
            }

            // Build children
            final boolean containsChildren = reader.hasMoreChildren();
            final boolean containsValue = !reader.getValue().isEmpty();
            final boolean empty = !containsChildren && !containsValue;

            sb.append(!empty ? ">" : " />");

            if (containsChildren) {
                while (reader.hasMoreChildren()) {
                    reader.moveDown();
                    buildRecursiveMessage(reader, sb);
                    reader.moveUp();
                }
            } else if (containsValue) {
                sb.append(reader.getValue());
            }

            // Build end-tag
            if (!empty) {
                sb.append("</" + nodeName + ">");
            }
        }
    }
```

This test

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final XStream xstream = new XStream();
        xstream.processAnnotations(Parent.class);

        // Deserialize
        final String xml = "<parent><message><type>15</type></message></parent>";
        final Parent parent = (Parent) xstream.fromXML(xml);
        System.out.println(parent.getMessage());
    }
```

prints out

```
    <type>15</type>
```

But it is not every the same content! It ignores for example whitespaces, `<foo></foo>` would mapped to `<foo />` and I don't tested XML entities like `&apos;` etc.

Maybe it's better to enclose your message in [CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) tags? Like

```
    <parent>
      <message>
       <![CDATA[
       <type>15</type>
       ]]>
      </message>
    </parent>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer .Actually I have more entities than message mentioned in the question above .. I wanted other entities to behave normally and only the particular node ( in this case message ) to be parsed as a string ) .

Comment: In this case I advice you to extend `ParentConverter` from `AnnotationReflectionConverter`. You can override `unmarshallField(UnmarshallingContext, Object result, Class, Field)`. If the field name (or field alias) is `message`, than you use `buildRecursiveMessage` for any else field you delegate the unmarshaling to `super`.

Comment: sorry, use `ReflectionConverter` instead of `AnnotationReflectionConverter` (=deprecated).